# Can API keys be added to the header using Retrofit2 android

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, api-key

Cannot get the API request to work with the API key. Have already tested it with a different API that doesn't use an API Key, which has worked. Makes me think that I'm not adding the API Key properly.

Tested it on [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71kYI.png) using the authentication tab which works well.

How can I send the key Access-Key and value 9xxxxxxxxxxxxx3 using retrofit2?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7w57.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call R.string.api_key, you don't get the String value, you only get its id, which is represented as a number. To get the value you need to have context and call context.getString(R.string.api_key). In our case, it is better to take it out from string.xml and place it in some class.
For example

```
object Constants {
    const val BASE_URL = "http://test.com/"
}
```

and then inside the retrofit

```
 return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
```

but if you want to get the value from string.xml you need to change **getInstance()** method from example add **Context**.

Answer (score 0):

You can send Headers like as:

```
public interface APIService {

//Login
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("loginAction")
Call<LoginModel> loginMI(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("pwd") String pwd,
        @Header("api_key") String api_key,
        @Header("secret_key") String secret_key
);
```

}

call the above API and pass the required Field and Headers.